# Why do I link my jquery inside a document.write?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the purpose of this code:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

as opposed to:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

..when linking jquery to my html file.

This might be a stupid question.  I'm new to web development.  My jquery won't work when I use the first code.  When I cut it down to the second code, it loads but it is glitchy.  I have this code just before `</body>`.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The second version is fine for most "normal" web pages. What do you mean "glitchy"? Please be more specific. You mention having the code just before `</body>`, but where is your code that actually uses jQuery?

Comment: I'm using aptana 3.  When I preview, the page doesn't ever stop loading, but the jquery function i've written works.  It makes aptana run slower as well.  I have the code that loads jquery just above the code that links to my jquery file.  I believe that is the right order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That line of code is usually used when you load jquery from a CDN, like

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

The second script tag will check if window.jQuery is defined (which means the script was successfully loaded from the CDN). If not load a locally stored version.

Comment: Great, I am loading jquery from a CDN.  Can you tell my why my jquery doesn't work when I use the first example in my question, and why it does work when I use the second example from my question?  I've been trying to figure it out for hours now.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of the first code piece is it checks if jQuery has been loaded or not. That is what

```
window.jQuery || ....
```

is saying. Either `window.jQuery` exists **OR** do something else.

If `window.jQuery` is `undefined`, it will

```
document.write('<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')
```

to load jQuery.

This can be useful when you dynamically load HTML content and you do not always need jQuery. If the order of events does not dictate exactly when you will need jQuery, you can explicilty load it when it is needed.

Comment: Great, that makes perfect sense.  So if the code calls for jquery, the document.write code will add the needed script line.  Am I understanding that properly?

Comment: @JasonCarrick Not really. That line won't inspect your script for a dependency on jQuery, it will just add it if it hasn't already been defined.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally Javascript events were attached to a document using an “onload” attribute in the  tag of the page. Forget this practice. Wipe it from your mind.
jQuery provides us with a special utility on the document object, called “ready”, allowing us to execute code ONLY after the DOM has completely finished loading. This is the key to unobtrusive DOM scripting, as it allows us to completely separate our Javascript code from our markup. Using $(document).ready(), we can queue up a series of events and have them execute after the DOM is initialized.
This means that we can create entire effects for our pages without changing the markup for the elements in question.